# dsPic33EP512MU810 external interrupt

Tags: external, interrupt, dspic

I would like use external interrupt for a touch screen chip. I could successfully configure the TFT chip right now. But fail to trigger my interrupt. I think I have correct configuration about my MCU.

```
void STMPE610_check_tp() iv IVT_ADDR_INT2INTERRUPT{
     Check_TP();
     STMPE610_WriteReg(0x0B, 0xFF);//clear the interrupt status
     IFS1.INT2IF = 0;
}



     TRISA.b7=1;
 Unlock_IOLOCK();
 PPS_Mapping_NoLock(23,_INPUT, _INT2);
 Lock_IOLOCK();
 INTCON2.INT2EP =1;
 IEC1.INT2IE = 1;
 IFS1.INT2IF = 0;
 IPC7 = IPC7 ^ 0x0050;
```

Answer (score 0):

The global Interrupt enable is missing:

```
INTCON2.GIE = 1;
```

Comment: I am not really familar eith the dsPIC but try to modify your Interrupt routine: `void _ISR _Int2Interrupt(void)`